# Automatic file encryption/decryption: detect file is closed in Mate/Gnome application

Tags: linux, shell, gnome, automation, mate

I'm writing a bash script to automatically decrypt file for editing and encrypt it back after file is closed. File type could be any: plain-text, office document, etc. I am on Linux Mint with Mate.

I'm stuck: can't reliably detect if file was closed in application so that script can proceed to encrypting it back and removing decrypted version.

The first version of the script simply used vim with text files. Script was calling it directly and hadn't been going any further until vim was closed. Now as I want to be able to do so with other files, I tried the following things:

xdg-open: exits immediately after calling the application associated with file type. Thus script continues and does no good.

xdg-open's modified function for calling an associated app: runs it inside the current script so now I see program exit. Works only if the application hasn't been running already. If it has, then new process is finished and script continues.

So what I am trying to do now is to watch somehow that file was closed in already running application. Currently experimenting with pluma/gedit and inotifywait. It doesn't work either - instantly after file was opened it detects CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE event.

Is it at all possible to detect this without specific hooks for different applications? Possibly some X hooks?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no X hooks for something like this. You would need to do something specific for each application as they will all handle file access differently from each other.

Answer (score 0):

The easyest way to do an ***"Automatic file encryption/decryption"*** is to encrypt your partition so all your files are (re)encrypted each time you save them

Another way is to encrypt your file at save time using the same editing program (like *LIBREOFFICE*)

Or use the hard way.. use the SCRIPT option in the CONTEXTUAL MENU in NAUTILUS (the GNOME file manager), you need to create a Decrypt_Encrypt BASH script and put it into:

> ```
> ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts
> ```

That BASH script has to do the following:

> decrypt your (previously encrypted) file
> to a plainText file

> store plainText timestamp data (in a variable)

> open plainText with your edit program
> (then edit & save it as plainText)

> check IF the edit program is still running
> executing every second the command:

> ```
> pgrep -a editProgramName
> ```

> re-encrypt plainText IF edit program is closed AND plainText has a newer timestamp

> delete the plainText

Then each time you want to edit a file just select that file in NAUTILUS using the CONTEXTUAL MENU (right mouse button) and then selecting the script OPTION from that menu selecting your script

Comment: Hi Joe, your answer is incomplete without a script